# Is my @@all array empty because one of the attributes is nil?

Tags: ruby

I am working on a scraping project and on pry I can see that it is processing @name  however price_range is nil and when I look into @@all array it is empty
this is my products class where the all array is empty

```
class Products

  @@all = []

  attr_accessor :name, :price_range

  def initialize(name, price_range)
    @name = name
    @price_range = price_range
    save
  end

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def save
    if @@all.include?(self) == false
      @@all << self
    end
  end
end
```

this is my scraper class where price_range variable is made. it looks good on pry @price_range returns an array of prices but for some reason price range is not getting logged in my products class.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'pry'
class Scraper

  attr_accessor :site, :content, :name, :price_range

  def initialize(site)
      @site = site
      doc = HTTParty.get(site)
      @parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML(doc)

  end

  def get_products
    content = @parse_page.css(".nav-item")
    content.each do |product|
      @name = product.css("span").text
      @url = product.css("a").attr("href").text
      @link = @site + @url
      get_price
      Products.new(@name, @price_range)
    end
    content
  end

  def get_price
    @costo = []
    prices = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@link)).content.scan(/[\$£](\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?)/).each do |price|
      @costo << price[0].to_i
      end
    @price_range = @costo.uniq.sort!
    @price_range
    binding.pry
    end

  end
```

and finally this is the CLI class where my site is defined:

```
class KefotoScraper::CLI

    attr_accessor :kefoto_scraper

      def initialize
        site = "https://www.kefotos.mx/aficionado/"

        kefoto_scraper = Scraper.new(site)
        kefoto_scraper.get_products
      end

      def call
        puts "welcome to the Kefoto Scraper CLI. To exit the program type 'exit' when prompt to answer a question. Enjoy!"
        main_menu
        end_flow
      end

      def main_menu
        puts "These are the services that Kefoto offers:"
        list_products
        answer = ""
          until answer.to_i.between?(1,6) == true
        puts "Enter the index of the product to see it's prices or type 'exit' to finish."
        answer = gets.chomp
            if answer == "exit"
                puts "Goodbye!"
                exit
            elsif answer.to_i.between?(1,6) == false
                puts "You entered an invalid number. Please enter a valid number to continue."
            else
                select_from_list_cli(answer)
                end_flow
            end
          end
      end

      def end_flow
        answer = ""
        until answer == "yes" || answer == "exit" do
          puts "to return to the list of products type 'yes' or 'exit' to finish"
          answer = gets.chomp
            if answer == "exit"
          puts "Goodbye!"
          exit
            elsif answer != "yes" && answer != "exit"
          puts "You did not enter a valid entry. Please try again."
            elsif answer == "yes"
          main_menu
            end
        end
     end

      def list_products
        Products.all.sort_by {|product| product.name}.each.with_index(1) do |name, i|
          puts "#{i}. #{product.name}."
        end
      end

      def select_from_list_cli(answer)
        selected_product = Products.all[answer.to_i-1]
        puts "These are the prices for #{selected_product.name}:"
        puts "#{selected_product.price_range}"
        average_price = selected_product.price_range.reduce(:+).to_f / selected_product.price_range.size
        puts "The average price for #{selected_product.name} is #{average_price}"
        puts "The max price is $#{selected_product.price_range.max}"
        puts "The min price is $#{selected_product.price_range.min}"
      end

    end
``
```

Comment: You say _"on pry I can see that it is processing @name however price_range is nil"_ and later on _"on pry @price_range returns an array"_. So is it `nil` or an array? Or are these different objects you are talking about?

Comment: The `@price_range` is not `nill` when i go into pry in the `get_price` method, but it's `nil` when i go into pry for the Products class `initialize` method. I think this is happening because I have pry in `Scrapper` therefor I may not be getting data from products class because it's created with Scrapper class. When I remove pry from all my classes I get an error for my method in CLI called `list_products` the error is saying product is not defined so my guess is that `Products.all` is empty so i can't iterate over it to make individual products.

Comment: edited my comment many times so you may need refresh. ty for the help!

Comment: _"FYI this code used to work a year ago and now that I am back it doesn't"_ – well, if your code didn't change, the cause must be outside of your code. Maybe the website changed? (different structure / price formatting)

Comment: no because i do get a price_range array when in pry 
  `def get_price
    @costo = []
    prices = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@link)).content.scan(/[\$£](\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?)/).each do |price|
      @costo << price[0].to_i
      end
    @price_range = @costo.uniq.sort!
    @price_range
    binding.pry
    end`
this does return the prices

Comment: This is the error i get without pry enviroments. Just by running the whole program `/Users/ac/Documents/GitHub/scraping_final/kefoto/lib/kefoto_scraper/CLI.rb:57:in block in list_products': undefined local variable or method "product" for #<KefotoScraper::CLI:0x00007fc0e25dbad8> (NameError)` That's why I am digging in the `Products.all` array because it seems like it's not able to grab my Products from `Products.all` maybe the initialize method or save method in `Products` I am lost lol. TY for the help!

Comment: The error is caused by a simple typo (see answer below). From your path, it looks like you're using git / GitHub – it should've been trivial to spot the change that caused this problem ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is:

> CLI.rb:57:in `block in list_products': undefined local variable or method `product' for #KefotoScraper:CLI:0x00007fc0e25dbad8 (NameError)

and it is referring to the block in this method: (I've wrapped the long line)

```
def list_products
  Products.all.sort_by { |product| product.name }
          .each.with_index(1) do |name, i|
    puts "#{i}. #{product.name}."
  end
end
```

You are passing the arguments `|name, i|` into the block, but within the block you use `i` and `product`. The latter (`product`) isn't defined so you get a `NameError`.

Change it to `|product, i|` and it should work.

Comment: TYYYY!!! i went straight to editing before going to see or look for any changes made ... lesson learned